# while storing data to firebase and updating state in react redux i get the following error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

i have written following code ..
this is my event action to store the events.

in eventAction.js

```
export const storeAndUpdateEvent = (events) => dispatch => {
dispatch(setLoading())
d.ref(`/events`).push(events).then(
    res => {
        if (res.key) {
            dispatch(addEvent(events))
            dispatch(closeModal())
        }
        dispatch(closeLoading())


    }
)
```

}

in eventReducer :

```
        case actionType.ADD_EVENT:
        console.log(state.events)
        return {
            ...state,
            events: [this.state.events,actions.eventPayload],
            isLoading:false
        };
```

finally in event.js

```
 {
            !isLoading ?
                events ?
                Object.values(events).map((event, index) => {
                    return (
                        <EventList event={event} key={index} />
                    )
                }) : <p>You Have'n involved in any events</p> : 'Loading .....'
        }
```

[the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU0dQ.jpg)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.events is not iterable
push../src/redux/reducers/eventReducer.js.__webpack_exports__.default
src/redux/reducers/eventReducer.js:35
  32 |     console.log(state.events)
  33 |     return {
  34 |         ...state,
> 35 |         events: [...state.events, actions.eventPayload],
     | ^  36 |         isLoading:false
  37 |     };
  38 | case actionType.UPDATE_EVENT:

Comment: It looks like events is an object at some point rather than an array, so you are trying to change the type of it in your eventReducer which will cause issues somewhere even when it does run because JS is dynamically typed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the `eventReducer`. You are outputting an array, instead of an object.

```
    case actionType.ADD_EVENT:
    console.log(state.events)
    return {
        ...state,
        events: {
            ...this.state.events,
            [actions.eventPayload.type]: actions.eventPayload.value   //guessed the properties of the payload
        ],
        isLoading:false
    };
```

Change the `eventPayload.type` and `actions.eventPayload.value` to whatever you have in your actual data.